# Counting substring of a string

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(countHi("xhixhxihihhhi"));
    }
    public static int countHi(String str) {
        if( str.length() < 2 ) return 0;
        if ( str.indexOf("hi") == -1 ) {
            return 0;
        }
        if ( str.length() == 2 ) {
            if ( str.indexOf("hi") == 0 ) return 1;
            return 0;
        }
        int i = str.indexOf("hi");
        return 1 + countHi( str.substring(0,i) + str.substring(i+1, str.length()));
    }

}
```

can someone explain to me why the result of the appearence of "hi" is 5 and not 3?

Comment: May you explain the problem a little more?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code. Pay close attention to the `String str`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the count of substring in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888605/how-to-find-the-count-of-substring-in-java)

Comment: Why do you include `str.substring(0,i)` in the recursive call if `hi` did not appear there?

Answer (score 1):

Because for the recursion you pass

```
str.substring(0,i) + str.substring(i+1, str.length())
```

instead of just

```
str.substring(i+1, str.length())
```

and since the initial string contains multiple `h`s, you create new `hi`s that weren't there at the start. 
Change to this:

```
public static int countHi(String str) {
    String s = "hi";
    if( str.length() < s.length() ) return 0;
    if (!str.contains(s)) return 0;
    if (str.length() == s.length()) return 1;
    int i = str.indexOf(s);
    return 1 + countHi(str.substring(i + 1));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A easier way to solve your problem with apache commons lang. Try this.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(countHi("xhixhxihihhhi"));
    }
    public static int countHi(String str) {
        return StringUtils.countMatches(str, "hi");     
    }
}
```

If you use Spring then..

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(countHi("xhixhxihihhhi"));
    }
    public static int countHi(String str) {
        return StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(str, "hi");     
    }
}
```