# Find same text within time range

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm storing articles of blogs in ElasticSearch in this format:

```
{
  blog_id: keyword,
  blog_article_id: keyword,
  timestamp: date,
  article_text: text
}
```

Suppose I want to find all blogs with articles that mention X at least twice within the last 30 days. Is there a simple query to find all blog_ids that have articles with the same word at least n times within a date range?

Is this the right way to model the problem or should I use a nested objects for an easier query?

Can this be made into a report in Kibana?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest query that comes to mind is

```
{
  "_source": "blog_id", 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "article_text": "xyz"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-30d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`nested` objects are most probably not going to simplify anything -- on the contrary.

---

> Can it be made into a Kibana report?

Sure. Just apply the filters either in KQL (Kib. query lang) or using the dropdowns & choose a metric that you want to track (total blog_id count, timeseries frequency etc.)

---

EDIT re # of occurrences:
I know of 2 ways:

1. there's the `term_vector` API which gives you the [word frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31914848/8160318) information but it's a standalone API and cannot be used at query time.
2. Then there's the [scripted approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61644143/8160318) whereby you look at the whole article text, treat is as a case-sensitive keyword, and count the # of substrings, thereby eliminating the articles with non-sufficient word frequency. Note that you don't have to use `function_score` as I did -- a simple [`script query`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html#script-query-ex-request) will do. it may take a non-trivial amount of time to resolve if you have non-trivial # of docs.

In your case it could look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
                def word = 'xyz';
                def docval = doc['article_text.keyword'].value;
                String temp = docval.replace(word, "");
                def no_of_occurences = ((docval.length() - temp.length()) / word.length());
                return no_of_occurences >= 2;
              """
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! i think i forgot an to describe an extra requirement: I need to find articles that mention `X` at least 2 or more times in the last 30 days. let me append the question

Comment: oops. i asked the wrong question again. what i meant was find blogs with articles on different days with word `X`. so ((blog1, article1 with X) and (blog1, article2 with X) with timestamps within 30 days). maybe i should just delete this question & start a new one. sorry for not asking the right question to begin with

Comment: haha. Yea it'd be better to ask a new one. But instead of deleting this one, why not upvote it ;)

Comment: done. i reverted the question & upvoted your answer. i'll ask a new question. thx for the help

Comment: asked a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62864603/elastic-find-text-between-records-within-time-range