# Elastic Find text in record group within time range

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic newbie here. I'm storing articles of blogs in ElasticSearch in this format:

```
{
  blog_id: keyword,
  blog_article_id: keyword,
  timestamp: date,
  article_text: text
}
```

Suppose I want to find all blogs with 2 or more different articles that mention `X` within the last 30 days. Is there a query to find all `blog_id`s that have different articles with the same word within a date range?

For example:

```
{
  "blog_id": "1"
  "blog_article_id": 10,
  "timestamp": 2020-01-02T00:00:00,
  "article_text": "... cups ..."
},
{
  "blog_id": "1"
  "blog_article_id": 11,
  "timestamp": 2020-01-20T00:00:00,
  "article_text": "... cups ..."
},
{
  "blog_id": "2"
  "blog_article_id": 10,
  "timestamp": 2020-01-20T00:00:00,
  "article_text": "... cups ..."
}
```

Searching for `cups` in date range [`2020-01-01`, `2020-01-30`], `blog_id` 1 should be returned but not `blog_id` 2.

Is this the right way to model the problem or should I use a `nested` objects for an easier query?

Can this be made into a report in Kibana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the below set of queries, collated into a single ES request.

The way to do about this is, first filter the documents based on the `timestamp` i.e. via [Range Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) and post that you can apply [`Term Queries`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) which would be like select distinct kinda of equivalent, and you can then add a [`Top Hits Aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) query pipelined to Terms Query.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_size
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2020-01-01",
              "lte": "2020-01-30"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "article_text": "cups"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "my_blog_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "blog_id",
        "size": 100,                          <---- Term Size
        "min_doc_count": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_document_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        },
        "bucket_count": {                     <---- bucket count
          "value_count": {
            "field": "_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above there are two mentions.

First one is so that you only get the results of aggregation query and second one so that you only return those blog_ids whose count is > 1.

Below is the sample response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_blog_ids" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1",                        <---- blog_id 1
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "my_document_hits" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "my_blog_index",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "1",                       <---- doc 1
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "blog_id" : "1",
                    "blog_article_id" : 10,
                    "timestamp" : "2020-01-02T00:00:00",
                    "article_text" : "... cups ..."
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "my_blog_index",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "2",                       <---- doc 2
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "blog_id" : "1",
                    "blog_article_id" : 11,
                    "timestamp" : "2020-01-20T00:00:00",
                    "article_text" : "... cups ..."
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for the quick response. i'll give it a try in the next few days (& upvote) when i build up the data set!

Comment: If I want to have `blog` be an Object, would I specify `blog.id` for the `aggs.my_blog_ids.terms.field` value?

Comment: Yes that's correct and that should work but note that ES has two different types of `json within json` structure. Do make sure you understand difference between [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) type and [`object`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) type in Elasticsearch.

Comment: Also if you make use of `nested` data type, you would need to make use of [`nested aggregations`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html).

Comment: @opster-es-ninja-kamal where do i send in my text search term `cups` ?

Comment: @FooL Please review the query once again. Have added it.

Comment: suppose I have a lot more documents. how do i know how many buckets/blogs there are total? i have something like this in the result:
`
  "aggregations" : {
    "my_blog_ids" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 5,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 2895,
`

should i start a new question to ask this?

Comment: @FooL Please check the query once again. I've updated what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you! is there a way to know the maximum number of buckets in my data set?

Comment: Please note the `value_count` aggregation I've added in the query. I believe that should do the trick.

Comment: sorry for the confusing followup question. i meant the number of `blog_id`s that satisfy the conditions. putting the `bucket_count` inside the sub aggregation only counts the number of documents inside each bucket/blog_id . thanks for all the help so far!