# ElasticSearch return documents with more than 5 term occurrences in a field

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like Elasticsearch to return documents that have more than 5 occurrences of a word in the  **body** field. For example:

```
{
  "query": {
     "bool": {
        "must": {
           "match": {
              "body": "baseball"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

I would like this query to return documents that have 5 or more occurrences of the word baseball in the body field. I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61644143/8160318

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution that you have is to use function scores with scripts in elasticsearch which @Joe mentioned in the comment. The other option is to store some extra data in the indexing.You can produce all 1-gram of on your text and store them with their occurrences as a list of objects in your document. Then you can easily make query on your data. Using script have some critical performance issues. If your system have critical point on performance, it would be wise to use this way instead of using scripts. If you do that, your query would be some thing like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "keywords",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "keywords.word": "baseball" } },
            { "range": { "keywords.occurrences": { "gt": 5 } } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```